# MUI Breadcrumbs - How To Hide First Item And Separator

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, breadcrumbs

I'm using the MUI Breadcrumbs component on a site I'm working on and I'm just about done but I'm trying to hide the first item in the path. I'm able to hide the actual word itself, but I can't figure out how to hide the separator.

For example, this is how it's structured now:

"W > X > Y"

This is how I want it to look:

"X > Y"

This is what I'm currently showing because I can't hide the first separator:

"> X > Y"

Anyone have any ideas on how to hide that first separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom class to the `Breadcrumbs` component like this:

```
<Breadcrumbs className="breadcrumbsCustomStyle"
```

and using css set `display: none;` for the first two `li` children of this class like this:

```
.breadcrumbsCustomStyle li:first-child,
.breadcrumbsCustomStyle li:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/breadcrumb-hide-first-pj6k6k?file=/customstyles.css) for a live working example of this approach.

Comment: Worked perfectly, not sure why I completely forgot I could do that with CSS haha. Thanks!